# How do I make a list of Names, Times and Positions of racers participating in a race with python?

Tags: python-3.x

Basically, I have to create a list of Participants for 4 groups (I would like to sort the groups), record their times and their rank in the race and produce a neatly formatted table of results.

I have tried using

```
racers = [(i, l[i]) for i in l]

places = sorted(racers, key = lambda i: int(i[1]))

print('1st Place: {}'.format(places[0][0]))
print('2nd Place: {}'.format(places[1][0]))
print('3rd Place: {}'.format(places[2][0]))
```

This is my current code:

```
l = []
a = int(input("Enter the amount of racers for Anstey: "))
g = int(input("Enter the amount of racers for Gordon: "))
h = int(input("Enter the amount of racers for Helps: "))
r = int(input("Enter the amount of racers for Rawle: "))
total_racers = a+g+h+r

print("Total Racers:",total_racers)

for i in range(total_racers):
  racer_name = (input("Participant Name: "))
  racer_time = int(input("Participant Time: "))
  time_name = racer_time,racer_name
  l.append(time_name)

print('\n',*l, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l` is already a list, you don't need to create another list as `racers` for sorting. If you want, you can assign `racers = l`

`time_name` is in form of `(racer_time, racer_name)`, the `key` to sort should be `i[0]`,  which is the `racer_time`, you are now using `i[1]` (`racer_name`) to sort

```py
racers = l
sorted(l, key = lambda i: i[0])
```

Or you should swap the position of `racer_time` and `racer_name`, e.g. `time_name = racer_name,racer_time`, because I think you would want to print the `racer_name` at the end but `places[0][0]` is actually the `racer_time`

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked well for me. However, as for the goal of my project, I was later informed that it must be an excel table.

Answer (score 0):

OP here.
The previous post did answer my question, but for anyone having to do something similar and export it to a Microsoft Excel worksheet, here's my code:

```
import xlsxwriter

# XLSXWRITER uses O as first row or column
row = 1 # 2nd row... leave room for Headers
col = 0 # 1st column

# Assign Names and Registration Numbers to Contestants
while True:
    print("\nEnter q to stop entering names", "\n")
    while True:
        fname = input("Enter First Name: ")
        if fname.isalpha():
            break
        else:
            print("Please ONLY use letters A-Z")
            continue
    if str(fname) == 'q':
            break

    while True:
        lname = input("Enter Last Name: ")
        if lname.isalpha():
            break
        else:
            print("Please ONLY use letters A-Z")
            continue

    while True:
        house = input("Enter House: ")
        if house.isalpha():
            break
        else:
            print("Please ONLY use letters A-Z")
            continue


    dob = input("Enter Date of Birth 'dd/mm/yyyy': ")

    while True:
        try:
            regno = int(input("Enter Registration Number: "))
        except ValueError:
            print(" That is not a valid number")
            continue
        else:
            break

    print("\n")
    date = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yyyy'})
    worksheet.write(row, col, fname) # First Name
    worksheet.write(row, col+1, lname) # Last Name
    worksheet.write(row, col+2, house) # House
    worksheet.write(row, col+3, dob) # Date of Birth
    worksheet.write(row, col+4, regno, date) # Reg. No. # 28/02/13
    row = row+1
```